# Confirmation Dialog to Run Trigger on a picklist.

Tags: visualforce, trigger, javascript

I have a pick-list on accounts that when a certain stage is selected and saved, all oops are cancelled (via trigger). Is there a way to add a confirmation after selecting the stage from the pick-list and selecting save, so that If the user Selects Yes within the dialog it will continue with the trigger otherwise, it will not make the change.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Checkbox field on the account and only have the trigger run on those accounts where it is set to true.  You will likely have to have a custom JS button that sets your account pick-list value so you can then invoke your confirmation.  If they confirm, then just set the new checkbox flag on the account to true, so the trigger will act on this account.

Comment: Also, vote here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l2cPAAQ

Comment: Can you further elaborate on this. Are those two separate ways of doing this via custom JS button or Check box or are they both supposed to act on the trigger.